# Retrieve content by string parameter in XML DOM

Tags: java, xml, dom

I wonder if there is an already existing system out there that does the following:

Consider a well-formed XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<root>
    <test>
    <name>Test</name>
    <complex>
        <value>Hello</value>
    </complex>
    </test>
</root>
```

Now what I want to do is retrieve "Hello" for example like this:

```
aSuitableClass.getString("test.complex.value");
```

I have made a small library that does this for JSON but I want to know if there is something like this for XML already out there. I know of XPath but that's not what I want because it uses "/" and so on.

If I had to make this myself I would assume DOM is the easiest for this as it is already in a tree structure. I would just have to create a string mapping.

Comment: So... `"test.complex.value".replaceAll("\\.", "/")` and then use XPath?!

Comment: I did think of that! I just didn't know if it would work exactly the way I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do something like

```
aSuitableClass.getString("test.complex.value");
```

you could replace the '.' characters to '/' and convert your query to an XPath expression in the getString method. I think that's your simplest option.
Here's an example of XPath [How to read XML using XPath in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java)